# How to Get All Server Side Traces in SqlServer from SSMS, stop it from SSMS and delete the log files

Tags: sql-server, ssms, trace

How to Get All Server Side Traces in SqlServer from SSMS(Active,Inactive), stop it from SSMS and delete the log files.
I need all traces saving into file as well as table.

I tried SELECT * FROM fn_trace_getinfo(DEFAULT). Some times few parameters are NULL. What does it mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Trace properties with `NULL` values indicate options were not specified when the trace was created. Properties are listed in the [fn_trace_getinfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-trace-getinfo-transact-sql) documentation and can be included a query for easy reference:

```
SELECT traceid, trace.property, trace_properties.description, trace.value
FROM fn_trace_getinfo(DEFAULT) AS trace
JOIN (VALUES
     (1, 'Trace options. For more information, see @options in sp_trace_create (Transact-SQL)')
    ,(2, 'File name')
    ,(3, 'Max size')
    ,(4, 'Stop time')
    ,(5, 'Current trace status. 0 = stopped. 1 = running.')
    ) AS trace_properties(property, description) ON trace_properties.property = trace.property
ORDER BY trace.traceid, trace.property;
```

Rowset traces (Profiler or SMO) will not have values pertaining to server-side traces, such as file name, max size, etc. Below are example results of the above query including the default trace and a running Profiler trace.

```
+---------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| traceid | property |                                     description                                     |                                      value                                      |
+---------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       1 |        1 | Trace options. For more information, see @options in sp_trace_create (Transact-SQL) | 2                                                                               |
|       1 |        2 | File name                                                                           | D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\log_175.trc |
|       1 |        3 | Max size                                                                            | 20                                                                              |
|       1 |        4 | Stop time                                                                           | NULL                                                                            |
|       1 |        5 | Current trace status. 0 = stopped. 1 = running.                                     | 1                                                                               |
|       2 |        1 | Trace options. For more information, see @options in sp_trace_create (Transact-SQL) | 1                                                                               |
|       2 |        2 | File name                                                                           | NULL                                                                            |
|       2 |        3 | Max size                                                                            | NULL                                                                            |
|       2 |        4 | Stop time                                                                           | NULL                                                                            |
|       2 |        5 | Current trace status. 0 = stopped. 1 = running.                                     | 1                                                                               |
+---------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The trace properties are also exposed as normalized columns in `sys.traces`. This DMV includes all legacy SQL Traces (but not Extended Event traces) regardless of whether its a server-side trace to a file or rowset trace returning data to a Profiler client. You may find it easier to query sys.traces instead. Example output from `SELECT * FROM sys.traces`.

```
+----+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | status |                                      path                                       | max_size | stop_time | max_files | is_rowset | is_rollover | is_shutdown | is_default | buffer_count | buffer_size | file_position | reader_spid |       start_time        |     last_event_time     | event_count | dropped_event_count |
+----+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      1 | D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\log_175.trc | 20       | NULL      | 5         |         0 |           1 |           0 |          1 |            2 |        1024 | 1048576       | NULL        | 2020-05-20 07:44:55.487 | 2020-05-24 08:25:08.983 |        1088 | NULL                |
|  2 |      1 | NULL                                                                            | NULL     | NULL      | NULL      |         1 |           0 |           0 |          0 |         1088 |           1 | NULL          | 94          | 2020-05-24 08:18:00.503 | 2020-05-24 08:25:08.983 |          74 | 0                   |
+----+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

**EDIT:**

A trace can be stopped and deleted in SSMS by executing [`sp_trace_setstatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-trace-setstatus-transact-sql) from a query window, specifying the desired trace id and status (0 = stop, 2 = delete). For example, the rowset trace with `traceid` 2 above can be stopped and deleted with:

```
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus 2, 0; --stop trace id 2
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus 2, 2; --delete trace id 2
```

Comment: Irrespective the trace is created in profiler,server it will be displayed in sys.traces ? 
Also How to stop a trace from SSMS ?

Comment: @abhaysreekumar, I edited my answer to address your additional questions. Note trace files will need to be deleted separately.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. sys.traces does not include Extended Events Traces. So How can we find Extended Events Traces?

Comment: Extended Event traces are exposed with the [Extended Event DMVs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/extended-events-dynamic-management-views). Unlike deprecated SQL Traces, XE traces are managed with DDL.